# Rather than stiffer springs, can I preserve my fine-tuned bed height using Nyloc nuts?

Tags: bed-leveling, bed

I've read a bunch of articles about getting better springs for my bed levelling screws so that I don't have to adjust it as often because standard springs vibrate loose as it prints.

However, would it be simpler and more effective to just use Nyloc nuts tightened against the adjustment wheels so that the wheels cannot rotate? Or some other form of mechanical prevention of the wheels turning? For example, tie a piece of string between the spokes in opposite wheels, so they cannot rotate much relative to each other.

Comment: Or locktite. why not just use locktite?

Comment: Stiffer springs should not be considered for novice 3D printer operators, this increases the chance of permanent damage in case of some beginners accidents (this is a general remark, not aimed at the OP printer experience/level).

Answer (score 2):

It's because the bed heats up. Since the bed can heat up to the point that locktite or nylon can soften, using those products to keep the screws from turning will have exactly the opposite effect.

Comment: Thanks for responding :) The bed heats to 50'C - i'm not sure that's enough to melt loctite. I guess the main question is: Do we simply want to prevent the adjustment wheels from turning? Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: Some people heat their bed to 100C to print ABS, some to 75C etc. The point of the springs is so that if the head crashes into the bed it won't get damaged. however as the bed (which is typically aluminium) expands, the stress could break or alter whatever locking effect you've put there; effectively causing the problem to return in short order. How short, I can't say.

Answer (score 1):

Does your bed already have washers on the screws?  The neopreme (red) washer under the screw head (in picture).  This is the German Reprap X400 design and is worth trying.

[image]

[image]